# how to change the text of element created onload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I used a plugin which creates buttons on page load and I want to change their texts on page load after that plugin creates them, so how can I do that using jquery?

I use bootstrap data table and I want to change the labels and the buttons texts like next and previous and I want to change labels like the show label

in my code this line of code `$('#results').DataTable();` creates the data table with its buttons so how cab I change the text if specific button.

**Html Code**

```
<table id="results" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>إسم الموظف</td>
        <td>رقم الموظف</td>
        <td>الإدارة</td>
        <td>مدير الجهة</td>
        <td>مدير الإدارة</td>
        <td>نوع الإجازة</td>
        <td>تاريح بدء الإجازة</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**js code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#results').DataTable();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datatables documentation says you can edit all strings used in it's interface by editing the language object.[Datatables documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language/)

If i want to change interface to french for example :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#results').DataTable( {
    "language": {
      "lengthMenu": "Afficher _MENU_ lignes par page",
      "zeroRecords": "Rien trouvé - désolé",
      "info": "Page _PAGE_ sur _PAGES_",
      "infoEmpty": "Pas de données",
      "infoFiltered": "(sur _MAX_ enregistrements au total)",
      "paginate": {
        "first":      "Début",
        "last":       "Fin",
        "next":       "Suivant",
        "previous":   "Précédent"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#your-button-id").text("this is your new text");

// or try this

$("#your-button-id").html("this is your new text");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use [one of the datatable's events](https://www.datatables.net/reference/event/) to make the necessary changes at an opportune moment.